# Android Kotlin not opening all links in webview app

Tags: php, kotlin, webview

My Android Kotlin `WebView` app opened successfully and navigate well through the usual URL address like mywebsite.com/register, but was unable to navigate through other links which I have used to power most of my webpages within the website like mywebsite.com/register/?route=dashboard. or ../home/?route=history.
the website programming language in totality is php ajax jquery with css and html.

**Below is my MainActivity.kt file**

```
import android.annotation.SuppressLint
import android.os.Build
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.os.Bundle
import android.webkit.WebView
import androidx.annotation.RequiresApi
class MainActivity: AppCompatActivity() {
    private lateinit
    var webView: WebView
    @RequiresApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.O)
    @SuppressLint("MissingInflatedId", "SetJavaScriptEnabled")
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle ? ) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
        webView = findViewById(R.id.FirstApp)
        webView.settings.apply {
            javaScriptEnabled = true
            safeBrowsingEnabled = true
            domStorageEnabled = true
            databaseEnabled = true
            allowFileAccess = true
        }
        webView.apply {
            loadUrl("https://vtuconnects.com.ng/login")
        }
    }
    @Deprecated("Deprecated in Java")
    override fun onBackPressed() {
        if (webView.canGoBack()) webView.goBack()
        else super.onBackPressed()
    }
}
```